# HttpClient GetAsync method not working in XamarinForms.iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, httpclient

In my Xamarin Forms application I am using **HttpClient – GetAsycn** method to get some data which is hosted in Azure.

The code to GET API call is working perfectly in Android. But which is failing in Xamarin.iOS. I am getting timeout every time I make the call.

I tried both

**modernhttpclient-updated**

**modernhttpclient**

for implementing the native http methods. But still it is failing. I am copying the stack trace for your reference.

```
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x0046c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:406 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <b238a3153e534349ad10ed0787f2157a>:0 
  at ZebraApp.Apps.ApiRepository.Client.RetryHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00063] in /Users/stezma/Projects/ZebraApp.Apps.ApiRepository/Client/RetryHandler.cs:40 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <b238a3153e534349ad10ed0787f2157a>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__48.MoveNext () [0x00080] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:276 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <b238a3153e534349ad10ed0787f2157a>:0 
  at ZebraApp.Apps.ApiRepository.Client.RestClient+<GetAsync>d__6`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00256] in <952a0a4af1c14e4eb63cdd96ae690f3f>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <b238a3153e534349ad10ed0787f2157a>:0 
  at ZebraApp.Apps.ApiRepository.Concrate.ValidateInfo+<ValidateGoodsAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00080] in /Users/stezma/Projects/ZebraApp.
```

**This is the code I am using for get request.**

```
  using (var client = CreateClient(request, handler))
        {
            var result = new HttpResponse(request)
            {
                HttpClient = client
            };
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, token);
                await CreateResponse(result, uri, request, handler, response, token, progress);
                result.HttpStatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (result.Exception == null)
                {
                    result.Exception = ex;
                    throw;
                }
            }


    static HttpClientHandler CreateHandler(HttpRequest request, Uri uri)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
        };
        foreach (var cookie in request.Cookies)
            handler.CookieContainer.Add(uri, cookie);
        return handler;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that the url you're trying to load is accessible from the device/emulator?  Have you tried loading it in mobile Safari?

Comment: Show the code causing the problem.

Comment: @ Jason : Yes .. I tried the same from Safari and which is working fine.

Comment: @Nkosi Added the code, FYI, the same code is working fine in Android

Comment: @Jason I can see, somewhat similar issue reported here. But not sure whether both are same or not (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3252)